# How to add and display new subnode on button tap?

Tags: swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have ASViewController with root node. In init I add some nodes. I need to display new node after button tap. How I can do it?

Comment: Please provide sources of what you attempted so far, and describe how your solution fails to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Layout Transition](http://texturegroup.org/docs/layout-transition-api.html)

```
- (ASLayoutSpec *)layoutSpecThatFits:(ASSizeRange)constrainedSize
{


  ASStackLayoutSpec *stack = [[ASStackLayoutSpec alloc] init];
  if (self.buttonState == SignupNodeName) {
    [stack setChildren:@[field, self.buttonNode, self.newNode]];
  } else {
    [stack setChildren:@[field, self.buttonNode]];
  }


  UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0);
  return [ASInsetLayoutSpec insetLayoutSpecWithInsets:insets child:stack];
}
```